# HTML Gridlike layout - CSS, tables or other?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been exposed to the commandment of 'no tables for layouts' for years now, but I'm wondering if CSS still has no easy (readable) way of doing grid layouts?

It's been ages since I last did web development, and coming back to it from WPF, CSS still seems like a very limited way of coding layouts.

What I'm trying to achieve is show in the [image]
<sub>(source: [chucara.dk](http://www.chucara.dk/images/css3layout.png))</sub>

Basically, I want my form to contain 5 columns:

- 1 holding s. Autosized after the widest element
- 4 taking up the remaining space in the parent container, divided equally

Next, I want to be able to place my inputs in this 'grid' so that two element on the same line share the space. Using a WPF Grid (or HTML table, I suppose), I'd just give my elements a column span.

So far I've only been able to find examples that nicely align a single input in the second row. I have tried CSS3 calc() and various other things, but no solution gives me what I want without adding way too much extra code.

Is it possible in native HTML and CSS3 to create the layout from the image?

If not, what is the cleanest way of doing it? (tables, [FreeWall](http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/), jquery, or other)

Fiddle here: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Z7sA6/1/)

Code Reposted from Fiddle:

```
<form>
    <div class="panel-heading">
         <h3 class="panel-title">Owner</h3>
    </div>
    <label for="firstName">Name</label>
    <input name="firstName" type="text" class="colspan2"/> 
    <input name="lastName" type="text" class="colspan2"/>

    <label for="street">Street</label>
    <input name="street" type="text" class="colspan4"/>

    <label for="zipCode">ZipCode</label>
    <input name="zipCode" type="text" class="colspan1"/>
    <input name="town" type="text" class="colspan3"/>
    </form>
```

My failed attempt at solving it using CSS:

```
form label {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 60px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right:20px;
}
form input {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom:4px;
    margin-right:2px;
}

.colspan1 {width: calc(50% - 100px);}
.colspan2 {width: calc(50% - 100px);}
.colspan3 {width: calc(50% - 100px);}
.colspan4 {width: calc(100% - 100px);}
```

I'd rather use jQuery or similar to achieve this than have to add a lot of extra s or combination of CSS classes to manage how many fields are on a line, etc.

Comment: why is this tagged WPF?

Comment: No idea. Must've clicked it by accident.

Comment: I managed to do (almost) what I wanted using tables here: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7sA6/10/

Comment: Maybe if you use something like bootstraps row system, and make it so that it works for forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the pixel values in the calc functions in CSS.

```
.colspan1 {
    width: calc(25% - 25px);
}

.colspan2 {
    width: calc(50% - 50px);
}

.colspan3 {
    width: calc(75% - 75px);
}

.colspan4 {
    width: calc(100% - 92px);
}
```

Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7sA6/4/) that I've made with some CSS modifications.

<s>You need to put them inside div containers (block level elements)</s>

```
<form>
<div class="panel-heading">
     <h3 class="panel-title">Owner</h3>
</div>
<div>
<label for="firstName">Name</label>
<input name="firstName" type="text" class="colspan2"/> 
<input name="lastName" type="text" class="colspan2"/>
</div>
<div>
<label for="street">Street</label>
<input name="street" type="text" class="colspan4"/>
</div>
<div>
<label for="zipCode">ZipCode</label>
<input name="zipCode" type="text" class="colspan1"/>
<input name="town" type="text" class="colspan3"/>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work the way I hoped. If I add another colummn, it spills over to the next line. Also, I was hoping to get the first column sized automatically. Might be that it simply isn't possible. (New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7sA6/6/)

Comment: You need to remove / reduce the right margin for the labels: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7sA6/7/

Comment: Chirag64: Ok, updated it with a 'worse' example: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7sA6/9/ I see no way I can set the calc offsets so that it pleases all combinations of placing inputs in 4 columns. I could create more classes, but then I'd be no better off than with just setting the widths in the HTML. Also, the first column is still statically sized, which is no good for localization. Maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way, and it simply isn't doable in HTML/CSS. Coming from WPF, this is a trivial task.

Comment: Going to try a different approach here. Putting all input tags in an inline-block div. http://jsfiddle.net/Z7sA6/11/

Comment: Last solution still isn't properly aligned. I've decided to place the labels above the fields instead for a better visual impression. I'll mark this as an answer as noone seems to provide a better one. Thanks for your effort!